# How to save value for key in *config file

Tags: c#, .net, windows, config

Try to store and to read some user definde value to *.config file
Code for reading from file

```
public int GetVolumeFromConfigFile()
    {
        return  Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Volume"]);         
    }
```

Works perfect

Try to update existing key with this

```
   public int SetVolumeFromConfigFile()
    {
       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Volume"] = "10";         
    }
```

Got error - file only for reading, change for something like this:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(label.Text.ToString(), box.Value.ToString());
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```

Got no errors, but nothing changed in file.

My *.config file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="PlayDemo.SettingsPlayIt" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<userSettings>
    <PlayDemo.SettingsPlayIt>
        <setting name="Volume" serializeAs="String">

        </setting>
    </PlayDemo.SettingsPlayIt>
</userSettings>
```

Just try to understand where I'm wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
config.AppSettings.Settings["Volume"].Value = "10";
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

This won't update the App.config in your project in Visual Studio, but the "ExecutableName".config in the bin folder of your project.

Comment: now it's work perfect. Try to understand correct me if I'm wrong this `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath` means, as you say, that programm change config file in bin folder, but what different beetween files in bin folder and in `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath`, means during programming, think it's the same file, just renamed each time by Visual studion during running program